# Javascript set white status bar on PWA as the new Chrome does

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, background-color, statusbar, progressive-web-apps

This is quite a new thing, since the new Chrome v.69 just came out, i noticed it has a white status bar with black icons (on android phone at least), since this is exactly what i'd like to achieve on my PWA set to "standalone", is there anyone who already know how to achieve this?

the     `<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff"/>` in the index.html `<head>` doesn't seem to do the trick, in fact it's still dark-gray semi-transparent (default android style i guess).

**EDIT:** the black or the translucent gray bars in this image is what i'm referring to https://themarketingtechnologist-ghost.s3.amazonaws.com/2016/Jul/colored_menubar-1468418798545.png

**EDIT 2:** from what i see the youtube official app also has the search bar with white background but the toolbar is transparent gray (as my PWA) so must be something only the new Chrome is "allowed" to do for now.

Comment: Where do you see this status bar? Can you add a screenshot? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @Mathias I'm talking about the smartphone statusbar with battery life, wifi icon, time, etc.

Comment: Mine has my theme color, not white. What do you see when you look at https://YourURL.com/manifest.json ? do you have the same theme-color there?

Comment: @Mathias i'm not talking about the search bar (that's only the case if using the pwa from browser or with manifest set to "display": "browser"), i'm saying the status bar, it appears if you set the manifest to "display":"standalone" and you open it as an app. btw white color is what i'd like to achieve not what i have now. mysite.com/manifest.json says "theme-color:#ffffff". edited with image

Comment: Don't know if this makes a difference, mine is "theme_color": (note the underscore, not theme-color with a dash). Perhaps try it in the manifest file with an underscore?

Comment: Mine too, my bad i remembered it like that but it's actually theme_color, so your status bar is white on your pwa? may i see a screenshot to understand, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181143/discussion-between-notsure-and-mathias).